# PHP Websocket failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED (anonymous)

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, php-socket

i learning the websocket in PHP but i don't know why have this handshake error.

My client.html :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
        var host = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8020/';
        var socket = new WebSocket(host);
        socket.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data)
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And server.php :

```
<?php

$address = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 8020;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket,$address,$port) or die('bind error');
socket_listen($socket) or die('listen error');
$client = socket_accept($socket) or die('accept error');

$socketread = socket_read($client,5000) or die('Failed to read');

preg_match("#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#",$socketread,$match);
$key = base64_encode(sha1($match[1].'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11',true));

$header = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
$header .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$header .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n";
$header .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";

var_dump($header);
socket_write($client,$header,strlen($header));


$msg = "connected";
socket_write($client,$msg,strlen($msg));
socket_close($socket);
```

However, I followed the Mozilla documentation on the handshake :/

Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I followed the Mozilla documentation on the handshake :/

While this might be you assume based on your code that only the handshake at the beginning is needed and that you can just use a plain socket directly. But WebSockets actually have their own message structure and also payload masking which you need to implement too. See [the actual standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for the details.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand :/

Comment: and why this code is working but not my code ? https://medium.com/@cn007b/super-simple-php-websocket-example-ea2cd5893575

Comment: @Errorj404: Notice the `chr(129) . chr(strlen($content))` in the code you refer to? That's the Websockets framing. It is simple for messages from server to client but more complex for messages from client to server since. Again, read the standard instead of just guessing how the protocol works. That's what standards are actually for.

Comment: My error is in this line -> $header .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n\r\n"; For don't get the handshake error i must  add two "\r\n" in Websocket-Accept headers, why ? And why chr(129) and not chr(127) ? it's the same number of bits.

Comment: @Errorj404: These are both requirements from the HTTP and WebSockets standards. Again, if you want to implement all this stuff yourself instead of relying on existing libraries please read the standards and don't try to guess how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Your request and still relevant ?

I send :

```
$key = base64_encode(sha1($match[1].'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11',true));
$header = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\n\r"
                        ."Upgrade: websocket\n\r"
                        ."Connection: Upgrade\n\r"
                        ."Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ".base64_encode(sha1($cartouche['Sec-WebSocket-Key'].'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', true))."\n\n\r";
```

I end up with 2 \n\n\r.

this part can't work :

```
$msg = "connected";
socket_write($client,$msg,strlen($msg));
socket_close($socket);
```

You must respect the frame

```
 0               1               2               3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
|F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
|I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
|N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
| |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 4               5               6               7
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
 8               9               10              11
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
|                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
 12              13              14              15
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
+-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
:                     Payload Data continued ...                :
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|                     Payload Data continued ...                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```